# Using trained model to predict classes with data of different input_shape

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, nlp

I have a saved model I trained on a small text (messaging) data corpus, and I'm trying to use that same model to predict either positive or negative sentiment (i.e. binary classification) on another corpus. I based the NLP model on a GOOGLE dev ML guide, which you can review here (if you think it useful - I used option A for all).

I keep getting an input shape error, I know that the error means I have to reshape the input to fit the expected shape. However, the data I want to predict on is not of this size. The error statement is:

```
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected dropout_8_input to have shape (519,) but got array with shape (184,)
```

The reason why the model expects the shape (519,) is because during training the corpus fed into the first dropout layer (in TfidfVectorized form) is `print(x_train.shape) #(454, 519)`.

I'm new to ML, but it doesn't make sens to me that all the data I try to predict on after optimizing a model should be the same shape as the data that was used to train the model. 
**Has anyone experienced an issue similar to this? Is there something that I'm missing, in how to train the model so that a different sized input can be predicted on? Or, am I misunderstanding on how models are to be used for class prediction?**

I am basing myself on the following functions for model training:

```
from tensorflow.python.keras import models
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Flatten
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import Convolution2D, MaxPooling2D

def mlp_model(layers, units, dropout_rate, input_shape, num_classes):
    """Creates an instance of a multi-layer perceptron model.

    # Arguments
        layers: int, number of `Dense` layers in the model.
        units: int, output dimension of the layers.
        dropout_rate: float, percentage of input to drop at Dropout layers.
        input_shape: tuple, shape of input to the model.
        num_classes: int, number of output classes.

    # Returns
        An MLP model instance.
    """
    op_units, op_activation = _get_last_layer_units_and_activation(num_classes)
    model = models.Sequential()
    model.add(Dropout(rate=dropout_rate, input_shape=input_shape))

#     print(input_shape)

    for _ in range(layers-1):
        model.add(Dense(units=units, activation='relu'))
        model.add(Dropout(rate=dropout_rate))

    model.add(Dense(units=op_units, activation=op_activation))
    return mode





def train_ngram_model(data,
                      learning_rate=1e-3,
                      epochs=1000,
                      batch_size=128,
                      layers=2,
                      units=64,
                      dropout_rate=0.2):
    """Trains n-gram model on the given dataset.

    # Arguments
        data: tuples of training and test texts and labels.
        learning_rate: float, learning rate for training model.
        epochs: int, number of epochs.
        batch_size: int, number of samples per batch.
        layers: int, number of `Dense` layers in the model.
        units: int, output dimension of Dense layers in the model.
        dropout_rate: float: percentage of input to drop at Dropout layers.

    # Raises
        ValueError: If validation data has label values which were not seen
            in the training data.

    # Reference
        For tuning hyperparameters, please visit the following page for
        further explanation of each argument:
        https://developers.google.com/machine-learning/guides/text-classification/step-5
    """
    # Get the data.
    (train_texts, train_labels), (val_texts, val_labels) = data

    # Verify that validation labels are in the same range as training labels.
    num_classes = get_num_classes(train_labels)
    unexpected_labels = [v for v in val_labels if v not in range(num_classes)]
    if len(unexpected_labels):
        raise ValueError('Unexpected label values found in the validation set:'
                         ' {unexpected_labels}. Please make sure that the '
                         'labels in the validation set are in the same range '
                         'as training labels.'.format(
                             unexpected_labels=unexpected_labels))

    # Vectorize texts.
    x_train, x_val = ngram_vectorize(
        train_texts, train_labels, val_texts)

    # Create model instance.
    model = mlp_model(layers=layers,
                                  units=units,
                                  dropout_rate=dropout_rate,
                                  input_shape=x_train.shape[1:],
                                  num_classes=num_classes) 
                                # num_classes determine which activation fn to use

    # Compile model with learning parameters.
    if num_classes == 2:
        loss = 'binary_crossentropy'
    else:
        loss = 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy'
    optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=learning_rate)
    model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=loss, metrics=['acc'])

    # Create callback for early stopping on validation loss. If the loss does
    # not decrease in two consecutive tries, stop training.
    callbacks = [tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(
        monitor='val_loss', patience=2)]

    # Train and validate model.
    history = model.fit(
            x_train,
            train_labels,
            epochs=epochs,
            callbacks=callbacks,
            validation_data=(x_val, val_labels),
            verbose=2,  # Logs once per epoch.
            batch_size=batch_size)

    # Print results.
    history = history.history
    print('Validation accuracy: {acc}, loss: {loss}'.format(
            acc=history['val_acc'][-1], loss=history['val_loss'][-1]))

    # Save model.
    model.save('MCTR2.h5')
    return history['val_acc'][-1], history['val_loss'][-1]
```

From this I get the architecture of the model to be:

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
dropout (Dropout)            (None, 519)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                (None, 64)                33280     
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_1 (Dropout)          (None, 64)                0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 1)                 65        
=================================================================
Total params: 33,345
Trainable params: 33,345
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

Answer (score 1):

For dimensions to be variable in `tensorflow`, they need to be specified as `None`.

The first dimension is the `batch_size`, which is why that's generally always `None`, but typically a batch of sequence data will have the shape `(batch_size, sequence_length, num_features)`. So a single sequence is usually 2D, with the length being variable, but the number of features of each "token" being fixed.

It appears you are feeding your model 1D vectors, and `Dense` layers have fixed input shape. If you want to model variable length sequences, you have to build your model using layers which accommodate that (e.g., convolution, LSTM).